# why can not define G := Group((1),(3,2));;

Tags: group-theory, math-software, symmetric-groups, computer-algebra-systems, gap

```
gap> G := Group((1),(3,2));;
Error, usage: Group(<gen>,...), Group(<gens>), Group(<gens>,<id>) called from
<function "Group">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at line 6 of *stdin*
you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
you can 'return;' to continue
```

before finding character table of permutation group S3  - 1,3,2

got error in above command

Comment: you could always try asking on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Are the users who downvoted and voted to close familiar with the software GAP? I don't understand the question so I cannot personally see one way or the other about whether or not this deserves downvotes or close votes. I expect if it deserved them there should be some explanation as to why in the comments, as well as efforts to engage with the OP, but I see none.

Comment: @Amzoti: I think, the OP just wanted any help for defining the group generated by that permutation in GAP environment. Maybe he/she was mistakenly looking for a isomorphic group with $S_3$. I vote it to be reopen. Thanks

Comment: The question is about the meaning of the error message in GAP, though it suffers from inconsistent notation and could be formulated better. I think it's fine to ask it here - the `gap-system` tag at stackoverflow.com seems much less attended. Try to debug your input and see how GAP parses (1) and (3,2) - you will see the difference which should give you a hint.

Comment: I downvoted the question because the OP did **not** show efforts to get in touch with [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html).

Comment: @scaaahu: Please don't make such conclusions just reading the GAP Forum: it is entirely plausible that the OP wrote to GAP Support, which is not a public mailing list, but did not get a quick reply from there and decided to repeat the question here.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov You missed my point. Had the OP said what you said above, I would not downvote. He did not say he tried GAP forum.

Comment: @scaaahu Indeed, I've assumed you are subscribed to the Forum or looked at the [GAP Forum Archive](http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/forumarchive.html), not that you'd like the OP to say this explicitly in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now after the question is no longer on hold, I can reply with more details:

1) The error about the wrong usage of `Group` usually means that the group can not be generated by the arguments. For example,

```
gap> Group(1);
#I  no groups of cyclotomics allowed because of incompatible ^
Error, usage: Group(<gen>,...), Group(<gens>), Group(<gens>,<id>) called from
<function "Group">( <arguments> )
```

2) What's then wrong with the arguments in the question? See how GAP evaluates various inputs:

```
gap> (3,2); # works OK
(2,3)
gap> ();    # this is the notation for the identity permutation
()
gap> (1);   # this is an integer one in brackets
1
```

Thus, `Group((1),(3,2))` tries to generate a group with an integer 1 and a permutation (3,2) as generators, what obviously does not make sense

3) What does `(1)` in the original question actually mean? If this has to be an identity permutation, one should use `()` - however, there is no need to add the identity element of the group to the list of generators, so `Group((3,2))` just suffices:

```
gap> Group((3,2));
Group([ (2,3) ])
```

4) This may be not the intended group, however, since the question contains "permutation group S3 - 1,3,2" - it's unclear what is the meaning of "1,3,2" here, but if the intention was to create a symmetric group of permutations of degree 3, here there are several ways to achieve this:

```
gap> Group((1,2),(1,2,3));
Group([ (1,2), (1,2,3) ])
gap> SymmetricGroup(3);
Sym( [ 1 .. 3 ] )
```

5) Finally, the following hint about character tables may be useful:

One can compute the character table "on-fly" for a given group, and if some methods depend on random states, the result may differ each time you call `CharacterTable` (conjugacy classes may be ordered in a different way). For groups whose character tables are available from [The GAP Character Table Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/ctbllib.html), the table will be retrieved from the library so the result will be the same each time. Compare `Display(CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(3)));` and `Display(CharacterTable("S3"));` to see the difference.

Comment: in another question, i can use wrong notation, it work, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453392/how-to-find-representation-of-group

Comment: @Seriesgroup: sorry, I do not understand what do you mean in your recent comment. The question linked there is still the same as yesterday.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: May I ask you to take a look at mu question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18043036/1842737. Sorry and forgive me for this asking Prof. :)